# Get user using membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm trying to get the user using membership. But the result of `MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser();` always return a `null` value. Can you please help me to get the user.

```
protected void lgn_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser();
    if (mu != null)
    {
      string[] user = Roles.GetRolesForUser(mu.UserName);
      if (user[0] == "Applicant")
      {
        Response.Redirect("/Applicant/ApplicantHome.aspx");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What event is handled in `lgn_loggedIn`? What does `User.Identity.Name` return?

Comment: its an asp:login event

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the user doesn't exist in your system, or is not correctly authenticated ?

**Return Value**

> Type: System.Web.Security.MembershipUser
>
> A MembershipUser object representing the specified user. If the username parameter does not correspond to an existing user, this method returns null.

Comment: While I'm logging, first time it returns the null value. But if i again try to log in. it get logged.